# Are Thalabi’s narrations on Qur'an 18:86 Sahih?

Tags: quran, tafseer, authenticity, uloom-al-quran, qiraat

> 1612 - أنا القاضي أبو بكر أحمد بن الحسن الحرشي نا أبو العباس محمد بن
> يعقوب الأصم نا الحسن بن علي بن عفان ، نا أبو أسامة ، حدثني عمرو بن
> ميمون ، قال : سمعت ابن حاضر أو أبا حاضر رجلا من الأزد يقول : سمعت ابن
> عباس ، يقول : « إني لجالس عند معاوية إذ قرأ هذه الآية » وجدها تغرب في
> عين حامية « فقلت ما تقرأ إلا ( حمئة (1) ) فقال معاوية لعبد الله بن
> عمرو : كيف تقرأها ؟ قال : كما قرأتها يا أمير المؤمنين قال ابن عباس :
> فقلت : في بيتي نزل القرآن . فأرسل معاوية إلى كعب فجاءه فقال : أين تجد
> الشمس تغرب في التوراة يا كعب ؟ قال : أما العربية فأنتم أعلم بها وأما
> الشمس فإني أجدها في التوراة تغرب في ماء وطين ، وأشار كعب بيده إلى
> المغرب ، فقلت لابن عباس : أما إني لو كنت عندكما لرفدتك كيما تزداد به
> بصرا في قوله ( حمئة ) فقال ابن عباس : » ما هو ؟ فقلت : فيما نأثر من
> قول تبع فيما ذكر به ذا القرنين في تعلقه بالعلم واتباعه إياه : قوله بلغ
> المشارق والمغارب يبتغي أسباب أمر من حكيم مرشد فرأى معاد الشمس عند
> غروبها في عين ذي خلب وثأط حرمد قال ابن عباس : وما الخلب ؟ قلت : الطين
> بكلامهم قال : فما الثأط ؟ قلت : الحمأة قال : وما الحرمد ؟ قلت : الأسود
> ، قال : فدعا رجلا أو غلاما فقال : اكتب ما يقول هذا « ([Source](http://islamport.com/d/1/ajz/1/102/296.html))

> أبو أسامة عن عمرو بن ميمون قال : سمعت أبا حاضر أو ابن حاضر رجل من الأزد يقول : سمعت ابن عباس يقول : إنّي لجالس عند معاوية إذ قرأ هذه الآية : ( وجدها تغرب في عين حامية ) فقلت : ما نقرؤها إلاّ { حَمِئَةٍ } . فقال معاوية لعبد الله بن عمر : وكيف تقرؤها ؟ قال : كما قرأتها يا أمير المؤمنين . قال ابن عباس : فقلت : في بيتي نزل القرآن . فأرسل معاوية إلى كعب ، فجاءه فقال : أين تجد الشمس تغرب في التوراة يا كعب ؟ قال : أما العربية فأنتم أعلم بها ، وأما الشمس فإنّي أجدها في التوراة تغرب في ماء وطين . قال : فقلت لابن عباس : لو كنت عندكما لانشدت كلاماً تزداد به نصرة في قولك : { حَمِئَةٍ } . قال ابن عباس : فإذن ما هو ؟ فقلت : قول تبع
> (Source: [Kashaf Wa-Al Bayan fee Tafsir al-Quran al-Thalabi on 18:86](https://quran-tafsir.net/taalaby/sura18-aya86.html))

Comment: What is your concern? No matter what the authenticity of the hadith is both recitations still exist and are valid.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I just want to know whether or not the narrations are authentic